# Sequelize Import Issues

Tags: sequelize.js

I am using Sequelize 6.3.4 and every time I try to import models I get the following error:

```
    var model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
                                   ^

TypeError: sequelize.import is not a function
```

Any ideas? I checked online and I cannot understand any of the online solutions.

Comment: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/upgrade-to-v6.html, https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/12175

Comment: In other words, if you're following tutorials/examples, it's a good idea to make sure they're using the same version you're trying to use. If they're not, it's a good idea to check the change log(s) to see why/how/etc.